# Using Azure Application Insight with tomcat application

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-application-insights

I am trying to intergate tomcat java web-application with Application Insight. I am follofing this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments but can't figure out what should I do first. Is it possible to add monitoring without changing code of application? What are my steps to complete integration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the guide you linked is for codeless monitoring. This means that you do not need to change anything in your code. The only thing you need to change is - depending on how you have installed Tomcat - the startup commands of your Tomcat. Plus, add the appinsights config file as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config

This section describes different ways for Tomcat installations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments#tomcat-8-linux